# Remove apostrophe in CFStringTransform results

Tags: objective-c, string, url

I'm converting Russian (or any language) string to a good looking Latin string to use in URL like `example.com/obezd-pedestala`

I use this code:

```
CFMutableStringRef bufferRef = (__bridge CFMutableStringRef)buffer;
CFStringTransform(bufferRef, NULL, kCFStringTransformToLatin, false);
CFStringTransform(bufferRef, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks, false);
CFStringTransform(bufferRef, NULL, kCFStringTransformStripDiacritics, false);
```

If I pas string like buffer `Объезд пьедестала`, I get `Obʺezd pʹedestala`. Letter `ъ` is replaced by `ʺ` and `ь` is replaced by `ʹ`.

I can use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to get a valid URL of course, but this is not a good looking URL I want.

How can I remove all those quotes and god knows what else characters from resulting string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [docs for `CFStringTransform()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTransform) note that it can take "any valid ICU transform ID defined in the [ICU User Guide for Transforms](http://icu.sourceforge.net/userguide/Transform.html)". From that and a bit of knowledge about Unicode categories, I came up with the following, which will strip such odd characters from the string:

```
CFStringTransform(bufferRef, NULL, CFSTR("[^[:Latin:][:space:][:number:]] Remove"), false);
```

Apparently, `kCFStringTransformToLatin` does not leave only characters in the Latin category. The above transform removes any character which is not in the union of the Latin, space, and number categories. You could customize that further with different character sets if you have different needs.

Comment: Wow, `CFStringTransform` is really powerful. Thank you. Is there a list of available transliterator identifiers?

Comment: How can I leave numbers in my string for example?

Comment: Oh. I originally had a solution to leave numbers, but I reworked things and forgot that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: In my answer, the only "transliterator" is `Remove`. For others, see [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-ICU-Transliterators) (includes both the general transforms and the script transforms). The other part, in the brackets, is a filter controlling which characters are affected. I'm using [Unicode character properties, including categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property).

Comment: Have you managed to get list of available transliterators IDs using Corefoundation API? Since some of transliterator usages expected an exception before passing string to transliterator engine, that could be a way of validate ID

Comment: @ugene, I don't understand. You're getting exceptions when you use certain transliterator IDs which are listed in the Unicode docs? I don't know of another list. You wouldn't normally need to construct a transform dynamically, so just test what you want to use and find out if you can at development time.

Comment: Ken, thanks for replay, I was just questioning about list of available IDs. You are saying it is in Unicode docs? 
I probably can gen a list via icu4c library for dedicated dat file, but that could be changed amoung new IOS version.
http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general#TOC-Using-Transliterators
One of examples of having that list, is posibility to check basic transliteration ID  for validness before user puts any text he want to transliterate. Agree that ID is internal string and shouldn't be used to display to user since it isn't in user friendly locale.