# How to customize CFString transliteration in Cocoa / Cocoa Touch / Foundation

Tags: swift, foundation, hebrew, icu, cfstring

I am exploring how to use `CFStringTransform` to [transliterate texts in Hebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Hebrew) and I am stuck with a few inconsistencies in which letters that should be pronounced differently are written in the exact same way or special cases that are not taken into account by Apple's algorithm.

#### *Kaf* (כּ → K) vs *Khaf* (כ → Ḵ)

- כִּי ("because")

  ```
  let string = NSMutableString(string: "כִּי")
  CFStringTransform(string, nil, kCFStringTransformLatinHebrew, true)
  print(string) // prints "ki̇y"
  ```
- שָׁכָחְתִּי ("I forgot")

  ```
  let string = NSMutableString(string: "שָׁכָחְתִּי")
  CFStringTransform(string, nil, kCFStringTransformLatinHebrew, true)
  print(string) // prints "şá̌káẖĕţi̇y" instead of "şá̌ḵáẖĕţi̇y"
  ```

While the *kaf* in כִּי is pronounced like a K in English, the *khaf* in שָׁכָֽחְתִּי is pronounced as in *loch* or *Bach* and it's typically transliterated as CH, KH or Ḵ. However, both letters are transliterated as K.

#### *Pei* (פּ → P) vs *Fei* (פ → F)

- פַּרְעֹה ("pharaoh")

  ```
  let string = NSMutableString(string: "פַּרְעֹה")
  CFStringTransform(string, nil, kCFStringTransformLatinHebrew, true)
  print(string) // prints "pȧrĕʻòh"
  ```
- יוֹסֵף ("Joseph")

  ```
  let string = NSMutableString(string: "יוֹסֵף")
  CFStringTransform(string, nil, kCFStringTransformLatinHebrew, true)
  print(string) // prints "ywòsép" instead of "ywòséf"
  ```

While the *pei* in פַּרְעֹה is pronounced like a P would be pronounced in English (and transliterated accordingly), the (trailing) *fei* in יוֹסֵף is pronounced like an F (and transliterated accordingly). However, both are transliterated with a P.

#### Trailing consonants with *pataḥ g'nuva*

From the article on [Hebrew vocalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) in the English Wikipedia:

> A patach on a letters ח, ע, ה at the end of a word is sounded before the letter, and not after. Thus, נֹחַ (Noah) is pronounced /ˈno.ax/. This only occurs at the ends of words and only with patach and ח, ע, and הּ (that is, ה with a dot (mappiq) in it). This is sometimes called a patach ganuv, or "stolen" patach (more formally, "furtive patach"), since the sound "steals" an imaginary epenthetic consonant to make the extra syllable.

However:

- תַפּוּחַ ("apple")

  ```
  let string = NSMutableString(string: "תַפּוּחַ")
  CFStringTransform(string, nil, kCFStringTransformLatinHebrew, true)
  print(string) // prints "ţaṗẇẖa" instead of "ţaṗẇaẖ"
  ```

---

#### Q: How can I change the behavior of `CFStringTransform` to account for these three cases?

From the [reference for `CFMutableString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFStringTransform), we see that `CFStringTransform` takes as the `transform:` parameter

> A CFString object that identifies the transformation to apply. For a list of valid values, see [Transform Identifiers for CFStringTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableStringRef/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Transform_Identifiers_for_CFStringTransform). On OS X v10.4 and later, you can also use any valid ICU transform ID defined in the [ICU User Guide for Transforms](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general).

From [the documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) it would sound like the rules for ICU transforms are flexible enough that they can be customized. There is even a [rule editor](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit?TEMPLATE_FILE=data/translit_rule_main.html) that can be accessed from [their playground](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit), but, while I have found [a Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27697591/remove-apostrophe-in-cfstringtransform-results) that deals with something tangentially similar, I cannot find a clearly documented way of doing it for RTL languages.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell through using it in Chinese and Japanese, `CFStringTransform`  works token-by-token rather than taking the word as a whole (which may be multiple tokens long) into account. Thus, transliteration will be limited/incorrect when multiple tokens need to be taken into account. I hope I am right in presuming that this is the root of the problem for your issues in Hebrew as well (please advise).

I have found transliteration to be much more accurate in such cases by using a `CFStringTokenizer` to tokenise a text, then getting the Latin transliteration of each token in turn with the `CFStringTokenizerCopyCurrentTokenAttribute()` method. An example of this – I think in Objective C, although the syntax in this case is quite similar to Swift – is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753141).